# How to disable comment highlighting in vim?

Tags: vim, tmux

I find myself on a new Ubuntu 22.04 machine running Vim 8.2, and I've found that all *comments* (in all languages) are highlighted, and it's driving me crazy.

**Edit:** This only happens when I'm in a tmux session (via SSH, from a Debian 11 system using GNOME term). `$TERM` is `screen-256color`.

How do I turn this off?

[image] [image]

[image]

[image]

My `.vimrc` is small, and doesn't have this effect on any other machines.

---

When I type `:colorscheme`, vim says `default`. However, if I type `:colorscheme default`, the highlighting goes away!

For now, I've added this to my `.vimrc`, which "fixes" the problem:

```
" https://askubuntu.com/q/1441256
colorscheme default
```

But why is this happening?

Comment: I'd give another terminal a try. And also start a clean bash session, i.e. without `.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this in a comment as a question instead of an answer, but I don't have the rep.. but

Have you checked to see if maybe there's an override in a system level vimrc such as
`/etc/vimrc`  or `/etc/vim/vimrc`

I don't have this specific issue so I can't repro and test myself but your question actually helped me solve my own issue which had to do with the default syntax highlighting for
#commented out
lines was such a dark blue my ancient eyes could not read it

after seeing your `:colorscheme` it led me where I wanted and solved my own issue with
`:colorscheme industry`

and that's when I discovered that there's not just your `/yourhomedir/.vimrc` but also `/etc/vim/vimrc` (at least on my Ubuntu system)

I am hoping maybe this will lead you to your why, and thank you for your question helping me find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Vim:

`: highlight Comment ctermfg=Blue ctermbg=none`

Comment: That actually makes it worse (brighter highlight).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it did happen to my editor as well after switching from `xterm-256color` to `screen-256color`.

I'm not sure why it happen, but on my end I just rebooted my machine and the highlights on comments went away.